# Finding the closest System.Color instance(s) using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I got this code working in C#. I would like help translating this into an idiomatic PowerShell script which would take an rgb or hex color definition as input and output the top 3 or 5 matches to the console including the color name and the rgb values. I am very new to PowerShell, sorry if this is asking too much.

```
    private static void FindMyColor()
    {
        System.Drawing.Color targetColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(red: 0, green: 128, blue: 0);
        var myStuff = EnumerateColors(targetColor: targetColor).OrderBy(tpl => tpl.Item1).ToList();
        int a = 0; // Pause the debugger here.
    }

    private static double GetColorDistance(System.Drawing.Color lhs, System.Drawing.Color rhs)
    {
        double sum = Cube(lhs.R - rhs.R) + Cube(lhs.G - rhs.G) + Cube(lhs.B - rhs.B);
        return Math.Pow(sum, 1.0/3.0);
    }

    private static double Cube(int value)
    {
        return (double) (value * value * value);
    }

    private static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Tuple<double, string, System.Drawing.Color>> EnumerateColors(System.Drawing.Color targetColor)
    {
        var candidateColors = EnumerateSystemColors();
        foreach (string colorName in candidateColors.Keys)
        {
            var color = candidateColors[key: colorName];
            double colorDistance = GetColorDistance(lhs: color, rhs: targetColor);
            yield return new Tuple<double, string, System.Drawing.Color>(colorDistance, colorName, color);
        }
    }

    private static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Color> EnumerateSystemColors()
    {
        var properties = typeof(System.Drawing.Color)
                .GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        return properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (System.Drawing.Color)p.GetValue(null, null));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, here is a PowerShell version to find the closest color.

First, we retrieve all of the colors declared as static named properties on the [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) type:

```powershell
$namedColors = [Drawing.Color] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property |
  foreach { [Drawing.Color]::($_.Name) }
```

To determine the distance between two colors, we can define a custom function using [Cartesian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points) for the three RGB dimensions:

```powershell
function Measure-ColorDistance( [Drawing.Color]$a, [Drawing.Color]$b ) {
  $sum = 'R','G','B' | foreach { [Math]::Pow( $a.$_ - $b.$_, 2 ) } | measure -Sum
  [Math]::Round( [Math]::Pow( $sum.Sum, 0.5 ), 2 )
}
```

To make it easier to specify the target color, we can define a helper function to create an [ARGB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh.aspx) color value:

```powershell
function New-Color( [byte]$r = 0, [byte]$g = 0, [byte]$b = 0, [byte]$a = 255 ) {
  [Drawing.Color]::FromArgb( $a, $r, $g, $b )
}
```

Finally, to find the closest color, we can get the distance between each named color and the target, and return the top colors ordered by that distance:

```powershell
function MatchColor( [Drawing.Color]$targetColor, [int]$top = 5 ) {
  $distance = @{ n='Distance'; e={ Measure-ColorDistance $targetColor $_ } }
  $distances = $namedColors | Select-Object $distance,Name
  $distances | Sort-Object Distance | Select-Object -First $top
}
```

Calling `MatchColor (New-Color -g 128)` will show the top-five results:

```powershell
Distance Name
-------- ----
       0 Green
      28 DarkGreen
   49.33 ForestGreen
   99.03 SeaGreen
   99.37 DarkOliveGreen
```

Comment: Your answer is soooooo great!, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

why not adding this code as type with add-type? And use it in powershell as `[myclass]::GetColorDistance(....)` - see here for more details

[Add-Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315241.aspx)